# For those running continous integration builds with Selenium Grid 2, how much can you expect to pay running 24/7 on Amazon EC2?

Tags: selenium, grid, amazon-ec2

I currently have a single linux box that is continually slaving through all the builds and tests.

but I think I am wasting money because some months there is lot of activity , other months none.

In the future, I think with more developers on my team, we have to order or decrease orders of new dedicated server boxes, have to predict the cost....inefficient.

Now, I saw Amazon EC2 is supported in Grid (not sure about grid 2), but I don't know how to calculate the prices on their calculator...

How much are you expected to pay for CI running on selenium grid 2 (1 RC, 5 browser instances running parallel), 24/7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Linux EC2 "small" instance costs about $750 a year if you never turn it off.  Depending on your suppliers, you can probably do much better with your own hardware, especially with a 3-year or so expected lifetime.